# how do I create a new azure management cache?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-caching, azure-powershell

Now that Microsoft has completely dropped the GUI support on the management portal, they are requiring me to install and setup and use windows Azure PowerShell to create a new managed cache service. As someone with not a ton of PowerShell experience. I cannot figure out how to successfully create a new azure managed cache. Does anyone have any tips?

I did the following:

- executed in PowerShell:

  ```
  Add-AzureAccount
  ```
- connected with login to Azure account
- executed in PowerShell:

  ```
  New-AzureManagedCache -Name test -Location "South Central"
  ```

and the error is:

```
New-AzureManagedCache : Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: managementCertificate
At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzureManagedCache -Name test-Location "South Central"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureManagedCache], ArgumentNullException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ManagedCache.NewAzureManagedCache
```

What should I do to fix this issue and get a new basic cache 128mb created?

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out - i needed to

get-azurepublishsettingsfile

and then

import-azurepublishsettignsfile "c:\filename.publishsettings"

and then it appears to be creating it now

Answer (score 0):

With explicit sku paramater:

```
New-AzureManagedCache -Name test -Location "South Central" -Sku Basic -Memory 128MB
```